# cannot construct the infinite type when using foldl

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I defined a binary tree and used my functions to create a new tree.

```
data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show)

singleton :: a -> Tree a
singleton x = Node x EmptyTree EmptyTree

treeInsert :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
treeInsert x EmptyTree = singleton x
treeInsert x (Node a left right)
    | x < a     = Node a (treeInsert x left) right
    | x > a     = Node a left (treeInsert x right)
    | otherwise = Node a left right
```

when I executed this in the terminal:

```
let nums = [8,6,4,1,7,3,5]
let numsTree= foldl treeInsert EmptyTree nums
```

It returned an error.

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ Tree a
Expected type: Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a
Actual type: a -> Tree a -> Tree a
```

however, after I changed foldl to foldr, it works.

```
let numsTree= foldr treeInsert EmptyTree nums
```

Can anyone tell me why? And what is the difference between foldl and foldr in this case, I am not clear with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two differences between `foldr` and `foldl`.  The important one is the way they parenthesize their calculation:

```
foldl (+) 0 [1..3] = ((0 + 1) + 2) + 3
foldr (+) 0 [1..3] = 1 + (2 + (3 + 0))
```

The other one is that they expect their first argument (the function), to take *its* arguments in opposite order:

```
> :t foldl
foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
> :t foldr
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

I believe the only reason for this second difference is to match the order that the expressions are written in the first code snippet.  You should choose between the functions based on which order of parentheses you want, and flip your function to match if necessary.

So in your case, the two options are:

```
foldr treeInsert EmptyTree nums
foldl (flip treeInsert) EmptyTree nums
```

Comment: I got it. I was really confused about the position of elements from the list and the accumulated value. Thank you very much~

Answer (score 1):

The signature of [**`foldl`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldl) is:

```
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

We apply `foldl` with a function (`insertTree`) as well as a `Tree` and a list of `Int`s, so that means that `b ~ Tree Int`, and `a  ~ Int`.

So that means that the thus far constructed `Tree` should be the first argument here.

We can solve it by using [**`flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip):

```
let numsTree = foldl (flip treeInsert) EmptyTree nums
```

`flip` flips the parameters, so `f x y == flip f y x`.

`foldl` means that for a list `[8,6,4]`, we will apply it like:

```
insertTree 4 (insertTree 6 (insertTree 8 EmptyTree))
```

We can also decide to use [**`foldr :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr) (notice that the order of the parameters has changed) like:

```
let numsTree = foldr treeInsert EmptyTree nums
```

then for a list `[8,6,4]` this will result in:

```
insertTree 8 (insertTree 6 (insertTree 4 EmptyTree))
```

Since the order in which elements are inserted in a `Tree` can have impact, the two are *semantically*, *not* equivalent.

Comment: I am still confused about foldl. Since the type signature of foldl starts from (b -> a -> b), for a list [8,6,4], I think it applies like this:  treeInsert (treeInsert (treeInsert EmptyTree 8) 6) 4. However, if foldl applies like this: insertTree 4 (insertTree 6 (insertTree 8 EmptyTree)), I can get the expected result.

Comment: Well it works with `foldl f z [x1, x2, x3] == f (f (f z x1) x2) x3`. But since we use `f = flip insertTree`, we thus "flip" te parameters, so `foldl (flip f) z [x1, x2, x3]` will yield `f x3 (f x2 (f x1 z))`.

Comment: It's really helpful, I got it, Thanks~~